# when i click button, ArrayList Value put TextView, how to TextView result input RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

When i click `ButtonSearchClickListener` ArrayList Value input hide(`TextView`), this result how to input `RecyclerView` `Adapter` `getData()`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editFilename, editName, editGender, editAge, editSearch;
Button addBtn, addFile, btnSearch;
TextView hide;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

ArrayList<String> arrayName = new ArrayList<String>(5);
ArrayList<String> arrayGender = new ArrayList<String>(5);
ArrayList<Integer> arrayAge = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
ArrayList arrayUser = new ArrayList<>(5);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String []filter = {};
    editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
    editGender = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editGender);
    editAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAge);
    editSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSearch);

    addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
    btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);

    RecyclerView rv= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);            
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this,getData());
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    hide = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hide);

    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new ButtonAddClickListener(this));
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new ButtonSearchClickListener(this));
}

class ButtonAddClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        Context context;

        public ButtonSearchClickListener(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String match = editSearch.getText().toString();

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayName.size(); i++) {

                if (match != null && match.equals(arrayName.get(i))) {

                    for (int j = 0; j < arrayUser.size(); j++) {

                        hide.setText(" 검색결과입니다 \n" + "\n" + "성명: " + arrayUser);
                        Log.d("name", "name" + hide);

                    }
                } else if (match != null && match.equals(arrayGender.get(i))) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < arrayUser.size(); j++) {

                        hide.setText(" 검색결과입니다 \n" + "\n" + arrayUser);
                        Log.d("gender", "gender" + hide);
                    }
                } else if ((match != null) && (Integer.valueOf(match) == Integer.valueOf(arrayAge.get(i)))) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < arrayUser.size(); j++) {

                        hide.setText(" 검색결과입니다 \n" + "\n" + arrayUser);
                        Log.d("age", "age" + hide);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "검색조건에 해당하는 정보가없습니다. 다시입력해주세요", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        }
    }

          // this recyclerview adapter code //

        private ArrayList<String> getData(){

            final ArrayList<String> userInfo = new ArrayList<>();
            userInfo.clear();

            if(hide !=null) {
                String asd = String.valueOf(hide);

                userInfo.add(asd);
            }
            return userInfo;
        }
```

Comment: Please could provide a better question, it's really hard to understand. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: answer is thx, i want when i click use "ButtonSearchClickListener", hide(TextView) is ArrayList Value receive, received value input recyclerview adapter "getData()", how to received value(in hide) input recyclerview

Comment: I'm sorry i can't help you

Comment: that`s ok, thx to translation substitute me

Comment: birth is of new language above